# Realoable spring with groovy beans

Tags: spring, groovy

Is there a way to configure a spring container to find multiple beans in a groovy sources folder, with reloadable functionality.
I know it is possible to use xml configuration to configure groovy beans one by one in a reloable way, ie:

```html
<beans>

    <!-- this bean is now refreshable due to the presence of the refresh-check-delay attribute -->
    <lang:groovy id="messenger"
            refresh-check-delay="5000" <!-- switches refreshing on with 5 seconds between checks -->
            script-source="classpath:Messenger.groovy">
        <lang:property name="message" value="I Can Do The Frug" />
    </lang:groovy>

    <bean id="bookingService" class="x.y.DefaultBookingService">
        <property name="messenger" ref="messenger" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Thank, Luis Oscar